# Comparison of objects in an array

Tags: javascript, object

Suppose I have the following array of objects:

```
myArray = [ { id: 'first', date: '2020-11-30', percentage: 10 }, { id: 'second', date: '2020-10-30', percentage: 20 }, { id: 'first', date: '2020-09-30', percentage: 30 } ]
```

Basically my question is how to find all the id's that have the same values, then compare their dates to see which has a higher value(I am planning on converting the string with Date.parse) and finally check which has the greater percentage, and then assign a variable to the condition.

Not really sure how to go about it, but figures it looks something like the code below or not, thanks for the help in advance.

```
 for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     if (myArray.id[i] === myArray.id[i]) {
         if (myArray.date[i] > myArray.date[i]) {
            if (myArray.percentage[i] > myArray.percentage[i]) {
               let stuff = stuff;
           }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: what the end result do you expect? output this object?

Comment: What is `let stuff = stuff;` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember objects with the `id` that you've seen earlier so you can compare them with the object you're looking at "now" in each loop iteration. A `Map` is a good way to do that in modern JavaScript, or an object created with `Object.create(null)` in ES5.

```
const lastSeen = new Map();
for (const entry of myArray) {
    const {id, date, percentage} = entry;
    const last = lastSeen.get(id);
    if (last) {
        if (date > last.date && percentage > last.percentage) {
            // ...this entry is newer than the previous one with the matching ID
            // Replace the previous one (and possibly do something with `stuff`?)
            lastSeen.set(id, entry);
        }
    } else {
        lastSeen.set(id, entry);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const myArray = [ { id: 'first', date: '2020-11-30', percentage: 10 }, { id: 'second', date: '2020-10-30', percentage: 20 }, { id: 'first', date: '2020-09-30', percentage: 30 } ];
const lastSeen = new Map()
for (const entry of myArray) {
    const {id, date, percentage} = entry;
    const last = lastSeen.get(id);
    if (last) {
        console.log(`Checking ${id} / ${date} / ${percentage}...`);
        if (date > last.date && percentage > last.percentage) {
            // ...this entry is newer than the previous one with the matching ID
            // Replace the previous one (and possibly do something with `stuff`?)
            console.log(`Replacing ${id}...`);
            lastSeen.set(id, entry);
        } else {
            console.log(`Not replacing ${id}`);
        }
    } else {
        console.log(`${id} is new, adding...`);
        lastSeen.set(id, entry);
    }
}
```

I haven't included setting `stuff` above because it's not clear what `let stuff = stuff;` in your original code was meant to do. You can find the latest ones per `id` in `lastSeen` or do something where indicated above to handle `stuff`.

In ES5-level code (but here in 2020 about to be 2021, I strongly recommend writing modern code and using a transpiler if you need to support obsolete environments):

```
var lastSeen = Object.create(null);
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    var entry = myArray[i];
    var last = lastSeen[entry.id];
    if (last) {
        if (entry.date > last.date && entry.percentage > last.percentage) {
            // ...this entry is newer than the previous one with the matching ID
            // Replace the previous one (and possibly do something with `stuff`?)
            lastSeen[entry.id] = entry;
        }
    } else {
        lastSeen[entry.id] = entry;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const myArray = [ { id: 'first', date: '2020-11-30', percentage: 10 }, { id: 'second', date: '2020-10-30', percentage: 20 }, { id: 'first', date: '2020-09-30', percentage: 30 } ];
var lastSeen = Object.create(null);
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    var entry = myArray[i];
    var last = lastSeen[entry.id];
    if (last) {
        console.log(`Checking ${entry.id} / ${entry.date} / ${entry.percentage}...`);
        if (entry.date > last.date && entry.percentage > last.percentage) {
            // ...this entry is newer than the previous one with the matching ID
            // Replace the previous one (and possibly do something with `stuff`?)
            console.log(`Replacing ${entry.id}...`);
            lastSeen[entry.id] = entry;
        } else {
            console.log(`Not replacing ${entry.id}`);
        }
    } else {
        console.log(`${entry.id} is new, adding...`);
        lastSeen[entry.id] = entry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi T.J, thanks for your answer. Please could you explain the solution, I tried implementing it, but var last = lastSeen[entry.id] gives undefined.

Comment: @user3843256 - It'll do that the first time it sees an ID, but not when it sees an ID it's seen before. In that case, `last` will be the previously-seen one and we do the comparison to find out whether we should replace that with the current one (`entry`) or leave the previous one (`last`).

Comment: I know it's meant to do that when it sees an ID for the first time, but it still displays "undefined" despite having multiple ID's with the same value.

Comment: @user3843256 - Not with the code above, see the snippets I just added.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I was just implementing it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array with an object and check if the key exist or if the wanted properties are greater.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 'first', date: '2020-11-30', percentage: 10 }, { id: 'second', date: '2020-10-30', percentage: 20 }, { id: 'first', date: '2020-09-30', percentage: 30 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (
            !r[o.id] ||
            r[o.id].date < o.date ||
            r[o.id].date === o.date && r[o.id].percentage < o.percentage
        ) {
            r[o.id] = o;
        }
        return r;
    }, {}));

   console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```